# Edit a Stored Procedure using ALTER?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have created a Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllRecords()  
   BEGIN  
   SELECT *  FROM my_table;  
   END //
```

Now I want to add a parameter to this Stored Procedure like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllRecords(id1 INT(4))  
   BEGIN  
   SELECT *  FROM my_table WHERE `id` = id1;  
   END //
```

How can I edit my Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have drop procedure first and then re-create it

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetAllRecords;
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllRecords(IN _id INT)
  SELECT * 
    FROM my_table WHEREid = _id;
```

And since you're using the only statement in your procedure you can ditch `BEGIN ... END` block and use a usual delimiter.

In case you're wondering no you can not use [`ALTER PROCEDURE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-procedure.html) in this case

> This statement can be used to change the characteristics of a stored
>   procedure.   However, you cannot change the parameters or body of a
>   stored procedure using this statement; to make such changes, you
>   **must drop and re-create** the procedure using `DROP PROCEDURE` and `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

Comment: we can use alter query?

Comment: `@peterm` any other alternative to this? ALTER ?

Comment: @naveengoyal No, `ALTER` can't be used in this case. [*...you cannot change **the parameters or body** of a stored procedure using this statement*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-procedure.html)

Comment: @NitishHardeniya See my comment to @naveengoyal. `ALTER PROCEDURE` is only used to change characteristics of a stored procedure. If you need to change parameters or body of a procedure you **have to** drop and re-create it.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the procedure

```
drop procecdure GetAllRecords//
```

And recreate it

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllRecords(id1 INT(4)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all ,This is not how you can pass the parameter in stored procedure.
You can not alter stored procedure, the way to do this is drop existing and create new one.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetAllRecords$$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllRecords(IN param1 INT, OUT pram2 Varchar(100), INOUT param3 Date)

BEGIN
select * from <tbl>;
< Your queries>
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

For Full detail of stored procedure 
please follow the link

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedprocedures.pdf

Answer (score 0):

To Alter a stored Procedure check this link

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345356.aspx

The best way is to drop the stored proceure and create it again

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GetAllRecords

CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllRecords(IN _id INT)
AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT * 
    FROM my_table WHEREid = _id;
END
```

Comment: OP is using MySQL not SQL Server, so the link you provided is useless. And the code in your answer looks very familiar...